# Pyspark pyspark.rdd.PipelinedRDD not working with model

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am not able to pass a RDD object to PySpark logistic regression model. I am using Spark 2.0.1. Any help will be greatly appreciated..

```py
>>> from pyspark import SparkContext, HiveContext
>>> from pyspark.mllib.regression import LabeledPoint
>>> from pyspark.mllib.classification import LogisticRegressionWithLBFGS
>>> from pyspark.mllib.util import MLUtils
>>>
>>> table_name = "api_model"
>>> target_col = "dv"
>>>
>>>
>>> hc = HiveContext(sc)
>>>
>>> # get the table from the hive context
... df = hc.table(table_name)
>>> df = df.select(target_col, *[col for col in df.columns if col != target_col])
>>>
>>> # map through the data to produce an rdd of labeled points
... rdd_of_labeled_points = df.rdd.map(lambda row: LabeledPoint(row[0], row[1:]))
>>> print (rdd_of_labeled_points.take(3))
[LabeledPoint(1.0, [0.0,2.520784472,0.0,0.0,0.0,2.004684436,2.000347299,0.0,2.228387043,2.228387043,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0]), LabeledPoint(0.0, [2.857738033,0.0,0.0,2.619965104,0.0,2.004684436,2.000347299,0.0,2.228387043,2.228387043,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0]), LabeledPoint(0.0, [2.857738033,0.0,2.061393767,0.0,0.0,2.004684436,0.0,0.0,2.228387043,2.228387043,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0])]
>>>
>>> from pyspark.ml.classification import LogisticRegression
>>> lr = LogisticRegression(maxIter=10, regParam=0.3, elasticNetParam=0.8)
>>> lrModel = lr.fit(sc.parallelize(rdd_of_labeled_points))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/hdp/current/spark2-client/python/pyspark/context.py", line 432, in parallelize
    c = list(c)    # Make it a list so we can compute its length
TypeError: 'PipelinedRDD' object is not iterable
```

Comment: If the provided solution solves your problem, please accept and upvote the answer to close the issue otherwise please comment on why it doesn't solve your problem !

Answer (score 2):

That's because you are using `sc.parallelize` on an `RDD`. The following is **wrong** :

```
sc.parallelize(rdd_of_labeled_points)
```

You are also mixing `spark-ml` and `spark-mllib` :

```
from pyspark.mllib.classification import LogisticRegressionWithLBFGS
```

and

```
from pyspark.ml.classification import LogisticRegression

lrModel = lr.fit(sc.parallelize(rdd_of_labeled_points))
```

In the first case, you'll need to `train` the model using the RDD as I stated above, example :

```
model = LinearRegressionWithSGD.train(rdd_of_labeled_points, iterations=100, step=0.00000001)
```

In the second case, you'll need to convert your `RDD` into a `DataFrame` to feed it to your model.

I strongly advice you to read the official documentation. There is also plenty of examples to help you start.

Remember :

- spark-mllib uses RDDs.
- spark-mll uses DataFrames.

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/hdp/current/spark2-client/python/pyspark/ml/base.py", line 64, in fit
    return self._fit(dataset)
  File "/usr/hdp/current/spark2-client/python/pyspark/ml/wrapper.py", line 213, in _fit
    java_model = self._fit_java(dataset)
  File "/usr/hdp/current/spark2-client/python/pyspark/ml/wrapper.py", line 210, in _fit_java
    return self._java_obj.fit(dataset._jdf)
AttributeError: 'PipelinedRDD' object has no attribute '_jdf'

Comment: Ok so you are actually mixing up ml and mllib. Don't do that please ! Which one you want to use pyspark.ml or pyspark.mllib ?